# Валидация логина регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php, валидация

Есть следующие правила для логина:

1. Допустимые символы: [a-z0-9._-]
2. Минимальная длина 3 символа, максимальная длина 24
3. Начинается с [a-z] и заканчиваться [a-z0-9]
4. Может содержать только один из [._-]

Вот элементарное выражения которое сразу приходит на ум:

**^[a-z][a-z0-9]*[._-]?[a-z0-9]+$**

Ну и соответственно отдельно проверка на длину. Ради спортивного интереса хотел проверить смогу ли написать регулярку которая удовлетворяла бы требованиям и работала без отдельных проверок на длину. Но ничего не могу придумать, может кто подтолкнет на мысль?

**UPD**

Совсем не заметил, как написал что должен начинаться с [._-], прошу извинения, должен начинаться с [a-z]. Данные в списке изменил. На счет ^ и $ это понятно.

Вот конечное выражение которую получилось:

**^(?=.{3,24})[a-z][a-z0-9]*[._-]?[a-z0-9]+$**

Comment: @RainRaus, про опережающие и ретроспективные проверки читал, но как то не додумался в таком ключе их использовать, а писал несколько другую регулярку и пытался отлавливать более одного вхождения символов [._-]. Спасибо. Сделайте ответом пожалуйста, я приму.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почитайте про позитивные и негативные проверки, и добавьте в начало выражения:

```
(?=.{6,30})
```

Это ограничит длину между 6 и 30 символов.
Ну и еще в Вашем выражении не хватает символов ^ и $ в начале и конце соответственно.

Comment: Решил воспользоваться данным прием в итоге узнал, что он не ограничивает макс. число символов в строке. Хотя ранее пробовал всё работало, теперь взялся опять за эту же регулярку - теперь не работает. Мистика, ну да ладно. Решил проблему следующим образом, по параметрам как в вашем ответе. **(?=.{6,})(?!.{30})** это нужно поместить в начало регулярного выражения.

Comment: Конечно не ограничивает. Оно лишь определяет, что справа есть какое-то число символов, чтобы не допустить других символов нужно либо явно указать якорные метасимволы конца/начала строки, либо сделать как Вы это сделали.  
Ваши проверки определяют: справа должно быть минимум 6 символов ( запятую можно убрать из квантификатора), но не должно быть 30 символов.  
Это же можно было достигнуть указав конец строки.

Comment: Якорные метасимволы указаны и тем не мене **(?=.{6,30})** эта проверка пропустит более 30 символов.